# I want value of query parameter from given url. Can I reduce this code in one line ? Or is there any other better way to do same?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

const url = `https://myWeb.com/abc/def/?xyz=sdfgkjhg&myName=javascript&status=married&sex=male&age=25`;
const queryParam = url.split('&');

let start = _.filter(queryParam,(param) =>{
  return _.includes(param,'start');
});

startIndex = _.split(startIndex, '=')[1];
console.log("=========="+start);
```

Comment: if it works, then it's a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

use url library

```
var urlPackage = require('url');
var url_parts = urlPackage.parse(url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
```

now you can access any varaible from query. For example

```
console.log(query.myName); // it will print javascript
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = 'https://myWeb.com/abc/def/?xyz=sdfgkjhg&myName=javascript&status=married&sex=male&age=25'.split('?')[1].split('&')
var final = query.reduce((m,p)=>{
     p = p.split('=');
     m[p[0]] = p[1]
     return m
   },{})
console.log('***',final);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the url using RegExp, [Array#map](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map.html) the results to an array of [param name, param value] pairs, and create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from the array. Now you can get any param value from the map by using `paramsMap.get('paramName')`.

```js
const url = `https://myWeb.com/abc/def/?xyz=sdfgkjhg&myName=javascript&status=married&sex=male&age=25`;

const paramsMap = new Map(url.match(/[^?&=]+=[^&=]+/g).map(s => s.split('=')));
  
console.log(paramsMap.get('status'));
```